# running a method in a loop

Tags: android, loops, methods, infinite-loop

I'm writing my first app in Android Studio. I have a method which is moving a picture in one of the activities and I just want it to work constantly. The only thing I know how to do is to run it by creating a button and clicking it but I can't find any solution that would work for running it without a button

That's the method I wanna run:

```
    public void ruchIceberg(){
    iceberg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if(iceberg.getX()<=-iceberg.getWidth()/2){
        setIceberg(iceberg);
    }
    setIceberg(iceberg,60);
}
```

Comment: So you want it to run as soon as the activity starts?

Comment: Yes, I want it to run when the activity starts

Comment: So you can call this method in the onResume method of your activity. That way as soon as your layout gets created, this method will run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I am a bit rusty now with Android, but...
The method I usually go with is to use [`Handler.postDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) as such:

1. Schedule a run when you want to start the task
2. In the `Runnable`'s body, re-schedule another run (if needed).

Example code:

```
//In your Activity.java
private Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
private boolean shouldRun = true;
private Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (shouldRun) {
            /* Put your code here */
            //run again after 200 milliseconds (1/5 sec)
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
        }
    }
};

//In this example, the timer is started when the activity is loaded, but this need not to be the case
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /* ... */
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
}

//Stop task when the user quits the activity
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    /* ... */
    shouldRun = false;
    timerHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(timerRunnable);
}
```